# get list of elements using document.evaluate using javascriptexecutor in java selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to evaluate the xpath to get the list of webelements using javascriptexecutor. i'm able to find the single element using `(WebElement)jse.executeScript("return document.evaluate('//input[@name=\"q\"]' ,document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;");` but when it comes to multiple set of elements it is throwing javascript error. can someone please help me in this. it will be lot helpful for me.

***Code that i'm using to get the result***

```
    try{
        Iterator<WebElement> arr=(Iterator<WebElement>)jse.executeScript("return document.evaluate('//a' ,document.body, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null)");
        int count=0;
        while(arr.hasNext()){
            count=count+1;
        }
        System.out.println(count);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

i have used all the types of `XpathResult` keywords.

```
ANY_TYPE
UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE
ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE
UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE
ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE
ANY_UNORDERED_NODE_TYPE
```

***Error Stacktrace***

```
org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: error reading property
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)
Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T19:05:32.194Z'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-S3RV3MH', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 87.0.4280.88, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 87.0.4280.88 (89e2380a3e36c..., userDataDir: C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:61398}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 43d3c47a7d6d9419891c6948ef2398bd
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:537)
    at demo.TestException.main(TestException.java:32)
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are not using the [Java Selenium API](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html) `findElement(s)` methods?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to build one small tool and for that i need this..

Comment: Got it, but `findElement(s)` does exactly the same thing without the pain. The torture of this is not necessary. But, good luck to you.

Comment: Actually i need it to check that for xpath of the saved html file... At that time findelements not works as that is not natural web page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use node type iterator, and add it to a javascript array and then return it :

An example code:

```
            String c ="results=document.evaluate('//a', document,null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);"+
            "var tagNames = [];\r\n" + 
            "while(node = results.iterateNext()) {\r\n" + 
            "  tagNames.push(node);\r\n" + 
            "};"
            + "\r\n return tagNames";
                        
            
            ArrayList<WebElement> arr=(ArrayList<WebElement>)((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(c);
            
            for (WebElement var : arr) 
            { 
                System.out.println(var.getAttribute("outerHTML"));
            }
```

Comment: I will check it and update here in comment in a while..

Comment: Thank you .. It's working and i'm accepting your answer